# How to grant rak_plan_read in stripe dashboard. Having the 'rak_plan_read' permission would allow this request to continue

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a subscription payment checkout session using this code:

```
    const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
        lookup_keys: [body.lookupKey],
        expand: ['data.product'],
    });
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        billing_address_collection: 'auto',
        customer: body.customerId,
        line_items: [
            {
                price: prices.data[0].id,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'subscription',
        success_url: body.successUrl,
        cancel_url: body.cancelUrl,
    });
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: The provided key 'rk_test_***' does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_xxxxxxx'. Having the 'rak_plan_read' permission would allow this request to continue.
```

I can't see how to grant the "plan_read" permission to my restricted key from the stripe dashboard.  The docs suggest "plans" have been superseded by prices.  How do I grant this permission?

Edit #1: My restricted key has these permissions configured in the dashboard:

```
Customers - Write
PaymentIntents - Write
Products - Read
Checkout Sessions - Write
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, Plans are generally [deprecated](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans) in favour of [Price objects](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/migrating-prices). In this instance, you should configure your restricted API key to have read/write permissions on the Prices resource which is listed in the creation UI.